# Mysql consultas 4 tablas

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

[image: mysql]

Por favor ayuda,
-los productos tiene material  se especifican en la tabla detalle_de_producto
-los pedidos contienen los productos y su cantidad pedida.

Comment: Por favor no pongas imágenes con el texto o código, pon el texto directamente, de esta forma a la gente le resultará más fácil ayudarte si tienen que copiar tu código o texto. Por otro lado, ¿que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: ¿y qué quieres obtener exactamente?

Comment: Edita la pregunta y ponlo todo como texto, no como imagen

Comment: gracias, people pero lo de @Javier Pintor es lo que buscaba, muchas gracias javier.

Comment: Nada, me alegro haberte ayudado. Bienvenido! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisa que los nombres de tablas y campos sean iguales, pero sería así:

```
select materiales.id_material, nombre_material, CONCAT(sum(detalle_de_pedido.cantidad_p*detalle_de_producto.cantidad_m),' ',unidad_medida) as cantidad_total
from detalle_de_pedido inner join detalle_de_producto on detalle_de_pedido.id_producto=detalle_de_producto.id_producto inner join materiales on detalle_de_producto.id_material=materiales.id_material
group by materiales.id_material
```